# Do I need the user input the Consumer Key and Consumer Secret when they login on Dropbox PHP Plugin

Tags: wordpress, dropbox-api

I'm currenty developing a wordpress plugin that using Dropbox API

I wonder do I need the user register their own cons key/cons secret and put it in the plugin or I've just use my own key ?

If I use my own key when release plugin, what should I do to protect the key ?

Thanks for advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you only need your own key. The user only has to log in using there account. They dont have to create an app and get a key i think? On the question how to protect your key, you should take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php and use "whirlpool". Or maby someone else got a better option?